# Can I change the urls that form the "better blog" extension?

Tags: magento-2.1, php, extensions

I installed the **"best blog" extension of Mageplaza**, but I do not want these URLs. In my project.

I want the URLs of this extension as

```
'domain/blog/id_post/url_key'
```

now the urls are in this way

```
'domain/blog/post/url_key'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's default 301 URL Redirect functionality for that.
https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-catalog/how-to-create-301-redirect-from-magento-admin-panel/

Comment: Yep i know, but i have 500 post more or less and 301 redirect would make the page much slower. I want to change how urls form within the code. thanks for your answer